# Like to make a list that has simple 'TABbed' formatting in HTML newsletter

Tags: html, html-email, tabular

Remember this is a question about code for an HTML email newsletter (code restrictions apply).

I want an un-ordered list of dates and events formatted so the dates run in a column on left margin and all the events follow to the right but left aligned, the way you would get with a simple tab stop in a text editor.

Should I be using a table for this or is there a simpler way?

As an added complication sometimes the event column will run 2 lines long and it would be nice to have the dates column run lines breaking it into:

1st line: date
2nd line: times

e.g.
Mon 6 Feb
8:30 AM

This is how text appears in a text editor which I'd like to approximate in HTML for email newsletter.

[image: Styling]

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler than a table. If this is for an email newsletter, tables are tried and true.

Answer (score 5):

It's tabular data. Use a table.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal webpage, I would probably use a `<dl>`. However, in email, you are best to use `<table>` elements to structure everything, because support for HTML and CSS is so inconsistent across different email clients. Use `<br>` to break content over two lines.

It might seem to break every best practice and accessibility rule from the last 15 years of web development, but if you want it to render correctly across most email clients, you don't have any choice.

These are some great articles to help:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/
- http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails
- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/design-guidelines/